# Scrollbar in Eclipse GUI doesn't exist

Tags: linux, eclipse, user-interface, scrollbar

I'm using Eclipse to develop Android apps. But I can't see all options in a window when I try to do anything because it doesn't fit to screen. Here's an example:

[image: example]

I can't see "Working sets" and anything if exists below it. It goes the same way at all windows which don't fit to screen. I've searched for a solution, I found something [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112084/how-can-i-scroll-down-in-this-window-provided-by-eclipse) but launching Eclipse with `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse` doesn't work either since there's no scrollbar at all. I've both tried it on Eclipse from Arch Linux's repository and built-in Eclipse in ADT. It just does not work. It's irritating that I can't scroll down in a options window to see the whole picture. Any suggestions/solutions?

Here's some system and software information if necessary:

```
Linux fuck 3.7.9-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 25 12:04:25 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Built-in Eclipse in ADT version: 3.8

Eclipse from repository version: 4.2.1-1

GNOME Shell version: 3.6.3.1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

If an SWT panel (Eclipse UI) is not written to scroll, it will not scroll. The wizard page you referenced doesn't scroll and there is no switch or setting that you can apply that will make it scroll. Can you not expand the wizard dialog to see all the content?

Comment: I can expand it but when it reached to the bottom of the screen, I'm out of luck. 1366x768 is just not enough.

Comment: No it's not. If I had to use such a screen for development, I'd be liable to throw it at someone. You may be able to tweak GNOME settings to use smaller fonts and spacing, but other than that you are likely out of luck.

Comment: Tweaking GNOME settings is a good idea, I've never thought of that before. Thank you.

Comment: Tweaking GNOME settings won't work. Changing font size doesn't apply to that window completely. Also changing screen resolution with xrandr won't work either. Using xrandr with newmode and addmode options doesn't work, it keeps giving an error like this: http://pastebin.com/KsWzHHCe Using xrandr directly with --fb and --scale options seems to work, at least I can see the whole thing in Eclipse but it has its own errors. I hope to find a solution to that addmode problem. When I find out what's wrong, it'll be OK. For now, I'm still out of luck.

Comment: Trying hardly with radeon won't work either. I desperately went back to fglrx because of heat. There's no way to change my screen's resolution and I've gave up for now.